# Confusion about example 3 of Section 18 in Munkres' Topology's Chapter 2 dealing with Continuous Functions

Tags: general-topology

In second half of Example 3 of Section 18 (in Chapter 2), that discusses Continuous Functions, the author claims that the identity function

$\mathbb{g}:\mathbb{R}_\ell \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

is continuous, because the inverse image of $(a,b)$ is itself, which is open in $\mathbb{R}_\ell$.

I fail to understand how $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_\ell$. Aren't open sets in $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ of the form $[a,b)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intervals of the form $[a,b)$ are the basis elements of $\Bbb R_l$. The topology generated by this basis provides us with the complete list of open sets. Note that an arbitrary union of basis elements is also open, so$$(a,b)=\cup_{\epsilon>a}[\epsilon,b)$$is open in $\Bbb R_l$.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

$[a,b)$ are basis elements of $\mathbb{R}_\ell$. You can take $\cup_{n=1}^\infty [a+\frac{1}{n},b) = (a,b)$ the union of basis elements which are also open. Therefore, $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_\ell$.

Comment: As this is your first answer. Here are some useful links as you are pretty talented with MathJax already. [Question Guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct consequence of lemma 13.4. $\Bbb{R}\subset \Bbb{R}_{l}$.